# Are words and space characters in a Text composable treated as separate Text objects?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

Here is the code:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {

    var textState by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val onTextChange = { text : String ->
        textState = text
    }
    Column(Modifier.width(200.dp).padding(5.dp)) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.width(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 4.dp),
                text = textState
            )
            Box(Modifier.height(10.dp).fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Blue))
        }
        MyTextField(text = textState, onTextChange = onTextChange)
    }

}


@Composable
fun MyTextField(text: String, onTextChange : (String) -> Unit) {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = onTextChange
    )
}
```

When I enter this line of text:
This is

It appears in the Text composable like this:

```
    This 
    is
```

To me, it looks as if each time I hit the space bar to start a new word, I have just created a new Text object. I guess the code works like this:
The first letter is "T", what is the min value? It takes one character: 1.dp. Ok, recompose the Text composable and so on .. until I hit the space bar. At this time the word `This` is treated as a whole new Text because when I enter `is`, this word is on a new line.
In short, it looks like I have changed the code to :

```
 Text("This")
 Text("is")
```

My question is

1. Is the  'Text' composable treated as a special case as the `instrinsic` measurements apply to the `words` it contains?
2. Is the space bar a magic device to "create" `Text` composables?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Why do you have `intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Min`?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use **`IntrinsicSize.Max`**

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.width(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)
) {
    Text()
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
}
```

[image]

Using **`IntrinsicSize.Min`** in your code the internal `MinIntrinsicWidthModifier` calculates child's minIntrinsicWidth = the minimum width that the layout can be such that the content of the layout will be painted correctly, and it means
having the width = longest word width in the `Text`.

[image]

Comment: That is because I am learning Compose and the book is teaching this value. And I want to know why it works this way.

Comment: Quite complex to explain in an answer. `MinIntrinsicWidthModifier` calculates child's minIntrinsicWidth = the minimum width that the layout can be such that the content of the layout will be painted correctly, then uses that `minIntrinsicWidth` to crate a fixed width `Constraints` to measure child.

Comment: It means that using `IntrinsicSize.Min` the minimum width =  longest word width.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It is only that I have no idea how `Column` knows to put `This` and `is` on two separate lines but when you enter a sentence like ` This is an example.` ,  and  `This is` is now on the same line. I know how to write a custom layout but looking at the code for `Column` , I am at a complete loss.

Comment: @ntos It is not clear what it is expected result.